# Buckminster action "create.product.zip" is unable to run successfully

Tags: java, eclipse, photon, buckminster, idempiere

I am attempting to run the buckminster action "create.product.zip" in eclipse Photon (4.8.0) with this properties file:

```
## buckminster.properties ##
#Where all the output should go
buckminster.output.root=${user.home}/buckminster.output
# Where the temp files should go
buckminster.temp.root=${user.home}/tmp
# How .qualifier in versions should be replaced
qualifier.replacement.*=generator:buildTimestamp
generator.buildTimestamp.format='v'yyyyMMdd-HHmm
target.os=linux
target.ws=gtk
target.arch=x86_64

product.features=org.idempiere.eclipse.platform.feature.group, org.idempiere.fitnesse.feature.group  
product.profile=DefaultProfile
product.id=org.adempiere.server.product

osgi.user.area=${user.home}
osgi.user.area.default=${user.home}
osgi.configuration.area.default=configuration
```

The error I am met with in the Console is:

```
org.eclipse.buckminster.pde.tasks.ProductVersionPatcher.getVM(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

The strange part about this is that I am able to successfully complete this action on an older version of Eclipse. If anyone could shed some light on this error I would greatly appreciate it.